# How to properly handle an empty array in flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to use an array to store selection status in flutter.
If isSelected[index] is true - container color should be change to blue else... depending on post.status value grey or white.

The code looks like this:

```
var isSelected = [];

color: (isSelected[index] ?? false) ? Colors.blue[100] : (post.status! % 2 == 1 ? Colors.grey[100] : Colors.white),
```

The problem is that I got error message: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Could you please advice how to properly handle an empty array in flutter?

Comment: use `Set` instead of `List` for storing your selection

Comment: indeed... it works now. Thank you :)

Comment: you could also just store index as it is implied as true if exists in `List` or `Set`. This way you could do `iterator.contains(index)`

Answer (score 1):

change you condition to something like this

```dart
color: isSelected.isNotEmpty && isSelected[index] ? Colors.blue[100] : (post.status! % 2 == 1 ? Colors.grey[100] : Colors.white),
```